# Split query string in VB.net doesn't find the delimiter

Tags: asp.net, arrays, vb.net, string, split

I am passing a query string between asp.net pages in a VB.net application. I recieve the string by doing the following:

```
Dim pagename_username As String = Request.QueryString("field1")
```

The query string made up of a URL and a user_id, and is sent via JavaScript.

The string is then split in the VB page, by doing the following:

```
  Dim parts As String() = pagename_username.Split(New String() {"|"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
            Dim pagename As String = parts(0)
            Dim username As String = parts(1)
```

This works fine for the following query string:

```
field1=http://**********/default.aspx|1
```

But gives an outside the bounds of the array error for the following query string:

```
field1=http://**********/docstore/browse.aspx?docstoreid=0&docstoretypeid=2|1
```

My suspicion is that the second string is too long??

If so, how can I solve it?

If not, what is the problem?

Comment: You should encode the url for the query string: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/829080/how-to-build-a-query-string-for-a-url-in-c and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10431107/how-do-i-send-a-url-with-query-strings-as-a-query-string

Comment: With the code you provided the issue can't be reproduced. Are you sure the string is exactly `field1=http://**********/docstore/browse.aspx?docstoreid=0&docstoretypeid=2|1`? It sounds like there's no `|` character in the string that throws the exception at all.

Comment: @sloth I have fixed it now, I split the username and URL into 2 parameters and passed them as 2 query strings. I also encoded the URL as suggested by Tim Schmelter. I think the problem was the & sign

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a query string, you separate the parameters by the '&' sign.  For example, the following query string has *two* parameters:

> www.someurl.com?param1=1&param2=2

In your case:

> field1=http://**********/docstore/browse.aspx?docstoreid=0&docstoretypeid=2|1

Notice the delimiter (i.e. '|') is in the second query string parameter, which is `docstoretypeid`, and not included in the value of `field1`.  Therefore, when you call `Request.QueryString("field1")`, you aren't getting the full string that contains the pipe delimiter.  That's why, your split fails and you are getting the exception.